# sql keep the first row according to an attribute

Tags: sql, mariadb

I wrote an sql to group by the SEASON in ASC and CHAM in DESC. How can I select the largest value of CHAM in each SEASON? To further development, I need to keep the CHAMPION_ID.

[image]

Comment: I'm lost . . . What does the second table have to do with the first?

Comment: What database and version, please?

Comment: We use the oracle database,version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1.

Comment: @jay That is not Oracle, it is an old MariaDB version 5.5. MariaDB forked from MySQL when MySQL was acquired by Oracle. Check `select version()`. MariaDB v5.5 was end of lifed last year. Consider an upgrade, it's free.

Comment: Champion_ID is a primary key, we need to use it to display the information. But sorry for the question is not clear, it is a HW and I don't know which parts I can post to prevent cheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can do this with [window functions](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/), but your database, MariaDB v5.5, is [too old to support window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB#Versioning) and a bunch of other things. I'd recommend either [upgrading MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/downloads/) or doing your work on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5) or using the stand-alone [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html).

You can do this without window functions using a [subquery](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-subquery/).

```
select *
from champs as c1
where cham = (
  select max(cham)
  from champs as c2
  where c1.season = c2.season
)
```

Pick only the rows whose cham equals the highest cham for that season.

You might be tempted to use a [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), but this will not show duplicates. For example, spring is all ties.

```
-- Only shows one row per season.
select *
from champs
group by season
having cham = max(cham);
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bc2e7d241f3d4f30bdde816cf0933131).

---

With window functions...

Add the seasonal [ranks](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rank-function/). This is partitioned by season and ordering by cham. rank() will assign the same ranks to ties.

```
select
  *,
  rank() over (partition by season order by cham desc) as season_rank
from champs
```

Then use that as a common table expression and select only the rows with seasonal_rank = 1.

```
with ranked as (
  select
    *,
    rank() over (partition by season order by cham desc) as season_rank
  from champs
)
select *
from ranked
where season_rank = 1;
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=aac79ce69ae26deb597d37349d18042f).

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Because this is the HW and I can't upgrade the Database. Is it possible to use the sql to do this question? But happy to know that this is an old method. I don't know the window function before

Comment: @jay Have they taught you user-defined variables?

Comment: they only teach us eg: select, where, from, orderby . But i still suck in this question, and i decided to use a stupid method. It can work separately, but when I use union, it does not work.

Comment: SELECT  T.TID,T.TEAM_NAME, T.AVERAGE_AGE, L.SEASON, COUNT(L.CHAMPION_TID) AS cham FROM TEAMS T,LEAGUES L WHERE L.SEASON='Summer' and T.TID = L.CHAMPION_TID GROUP BY T.TID,T.TEAM_NAME, T.AVERAGE_AGE, L.SEASON ORDER BY cham DESC,T.TID fetch first 1 rows only

UNION 

SELECT  T.TID,T.TEAM_NAME, T.AVERAGE_AGE, L.SEASON, COUNT(L.CHAMPION_TID) AS cham FROM TEAMS T,LEAGUES L WHERE L.SEASON='Spring' and T.TID = L.CHAMPION_TID GROUP BY T.TID,T.TEAM_NAME, T.AVERAGE_AGE, L.SEASON ORDER BY cham DESC,T.TID fetch first 1 rows only;